# Multiple configuration for one class

Tags: c#, solid-principles

These last days, I try to understand how I could change my code in order to follow `SOLID` principles.

But with this example, I can't find a proper way to deal with.

A Product has a `Name`, and a `BarCode`:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
}
```

Also, some products must have a `Batch Number`, and/or a `Sale Deadline Date`:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public bool IsBatchNumberManaged { get; set; }
    public bool IsSaleDeadlineDateManaged { get; set; }
}
```

I have some `Stock`, which involve these `Products`, plus some data: `Quantity`, `Batch Number` if needed, `Sale Deadline Date` if needed.

```
public class Stock
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    // should be null if Product is not managed by BN,
    // else it has not to be null
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    // should be null if Product is not managed by SDD,
    // else it has not to be null
    public DateTime? SaleDeadlineDate { get; set; }
}
```

---

I presume that my `Stock` records should be built like this:

```
public interface IStock
{
    Product Product { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public interface IBatchNumberManagedStock : IStock
{
    string BatchNumber { get; set; }
}

public interface ISaleDeadlineDateManagedStock : IStock
{
    DateTime SaleDeadlineDate { get; set; }
}

public class Stock : IStock
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here comes the classes I am not confortable with:

```
public class BatchNumberManagedStock : IStock, IBatchNumberManagedStock
{ ... }

public class SaleDeadlineDateManagedStock : IStock, ISaleDeadlineManagedStock
{ ... }

public class BatchNumberAndSaleDeadlineDateManagedStock : IStock, IBatchNumberManagedStock, ISaleDeadlineDateManagedStock
{ ... }
```

---

Do I have to create another class for each possible configuration?
What if now I have this?:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public bool IsSerialNumberManaged { get; set; }
}
```

I have to create four new classes, *just to implement this very new property* ?

```
public interface ISerialNumberManagedStock : IStock
{
    string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

public class SerialNumberManagedStock : IStock, ISerialNumberManagedStock { ... }
public class BatchNumberAndSerialNumberManagedStock : ... { ... }
public class SaleDeadlineDateAndSerialNumberManagedStock : ... { ... }
public class BatchNumberAndSaleDeadlineDateAndSerialNumberManagedStock : ... { ... }
```

---

Is ***this*** a proper way to implement this problem? I really feel like I created a kraken, which will involve a big amount of code-writing-work for each new configuration of the `Product` class...

---

A little bit in the future:
<*Hey look, for these kinds of `Product`, **we need the BatchNumber to be the SaleDeadlineDate in format "yyyyMMdd"**.*>
Should I *again* build new classes?

---

Oh, and I forgot to tell you! **Stock of SerialNumber managed Products has the quantity to be 1!**

Comment: If you have a property that doesn't have a  value, it's still OK to define that field on a class; just allowing (in your validation & through selection of the appropriate data type) to allow that property to be null.  You only need to define other classes if this those fields must not be used; which is different to allowing them to be null.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with your question, but as a general tip: name your booleans in such a way that the name can only imply true or false. For instance, HasBatchNumberManagement or IsSaleDeadlineManaged. That makes the code more readable. Without looking at the type, it looks like "BatchNumberManagement " is a complex object that handles the management of batch numbers, whereas "HasBatchNumberManagement" can only be something that is either true or false.

Comment: Exactly which SOLID principle are you hoping to adhere to with this?

Comment: I firstly tried to apply the open-close principle, then interface seggregation. I probably did some mistakes, as I am quite new to these principles ; this is the main reason about this question!

Comment: Behaviors should drive interfaces, not data members. It's usually unnecessary to have multiple classes where there's no behavior change. In other words you could use nullable references or something like `Optional<BatchNumber>` and deal with valid permutations using factory methods. Another approach you could take is to use some kind of `Product -- "*" ProductAttribute` composition, but it might make the design more complex for nothing, unless you need dynamic attributes.

Comment: I understand factories, but I am not confident about it. May you please give a brief example on how factories could help with my example?

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda Your code indicates Stock with a batch number can potentially have sales deadlines that are *independent* of the batch. Is a sales deadline ever a property of a batch rather than individual stock?

Comment: @pere57 It's right, each product of a same batch should have the same sale deadline. I didn't mention this point because I wanted to focus of this problem. The batch - sale deadline association will be checked with DB values, later.

Comment: @MaximeRecuerda Follow up question: can a product can really be managed by two+ things at the same time e.g. both batch number and serial number or both batch and sales deadline, or etc.?

Comment: @pere57 Sure, this is the point of this question. A product can have a batch number, and if so, we have to fill it. Each of these management is really independent of the others.

Answer (score 1):

This might help the way your problem is currently stated:

Do you notice that all of your examples regarding 'extra' properties is about management? What about breaking out that into its own concept and then apply the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

```
public interface IProductManagement
{
  void Accept(IProductManagementVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IManagedByBatchNumber
  : IProductManagement
{
  public int BatchNo { get; set; }      
}

public interface IManagedBySerialNumber
  : IProductManagement
{
  public int SerialNo { get; set; }   
}

... etc ...

public interface IProductManagementVisitor
{
  void Visit(IManagedByBatchNumber management);
  void Visit(IManagedBySerialNumber management);
  ...etc...
}
```

And update Stock:

```
public class Stock
{
  public Product Product { get; set; }
  public int Quantity { get; set; }
  public IProductManagement Management { get; set; }
}
```

Add visitors:

```
public class BatchNumberPrintingVisitor
  : IProductManagementVisitor
{
  public void Visit(IManagedByBatchNumber management)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Batch: {management.BatchNo}");
  }
  public void Visit(IManagedBySerialNumber management)
  { /* ignore */ }
}
```

Add managers:

```
public class BatchNumberManagement
  : IManagedByBatchNumber
{
  public int BatchNo { get; set; }

  public void Accept(IProductManagementVisitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}

public class SerialNumberManagement
  : IManagedBySerialNumber
{
  public int SerialNo { get; set; }

  public void Accept(IProductManagementVisitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}

public class CompositeProductManagement
  : IProductManagement
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<IProductManagement> parts_; 

  public CompositeProductManagement(params IProductManagement[] parts)
  {
    parts_ = parts.ToArray();
  }

  public void Accept(IProductManagementVisitor visitor)
  {
    foreach (var part in parts_)
    {
      part.Accept(visitor);
    }
  }
}
```

And use:

```
var stockManagedByBatch = new Stock
{
  Product =  "A",
  Quantity = 1,
  Management = new BatchNumberManagement
  {
    BatchNo = 123456
  }
};

var stockManagedByBatchAndSerialNo = new Stock
{
  Product = "B",
  Quantity = 1,
  Management = new CompositeProductManagement(
    new BatchNumberManagement { BatchNo = 123456 },
    new SerialNumberManagement { SerialNo = 9870 }
  }
};

var stocks = new [] { stockManagedByBatch, stockManagedByBatchAndSerialNo };

// print batch# of all stocks managed by batch to console
var printingVisitor = new BatchNumberPrintingVisitor();

foreach (var stock in stocks)
{
  stock.Management.Accept(printingVisitor);
}
```

Note that the `IProductManagementVisitor` interface could also be considered breaking the SOLID principles as adding a new management concept require all visitors to be updated. If this actually begins to hurt, one could switch to the dynamic visitor pattern:

```
public interface IProductManagement
{
  void Accept(IProductManagementVisitor visitor);
}

public interface IManagedByBatchNumber
  : IProductManagement
{
  public int BatchNo { get; set; }      
}

public interface IProductManagementVisitor
{
  void Visit(IProductManagement management);
}

public class BatchNumberPrintingVisitor
  : IProductManagementVisitor
{
  void Visit(IProductManagement management)
  {
    var batchManagement = management as IManagedByBatchNumber;
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, batchManagement))
      return;

    Console.WriteLine($"Batch number: {batchManagement.BatchNo}");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your point of view is very sympathic. I really like your visitor idea, I will take a long look at what you posted there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overdoing it. Unless there's a good reason to create separate interface for all property extensions, why not just

```
public interface IStock
{
    Product Product { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
    bool IsBatchNumberManaged { get; }
    string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    bool IsSaleDeadlineDateManaged { get; }
    DateTime? SaleDeadlineDate { get; set; }
}

public class Stock : IStock
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public IsBatchNumberManaged { get { return BatchNumber != null;} }
    string BatchNumber { get; set; }

    IsSaleDeadlineDateManaged { get { return SaleDeadlineDate != null;} }
    DateTime? SaleDeadlineDate { get; set; }    

}
```

Comment: I feel like this solution is not correct, because `IsBatchNumberManaged` relies on `BatchNumber`, while it should be the opposite. It's only if `IsBatchNumberManaged` is set to false that `BatchNumber` could (and have to) be null.

Comment: It all depends how you are using the class in your code. This implementation is meant to be used so that you can easily filter all that has BatchNumber by using IsBatchNumberManaged -boolean. Obviously you can do it any way you like, but the key point was that not every property needs to have their own interface.

Comment: I'd even argue that `IStock` and `IProduct` are useless abstractions most of the time, unless you really have multiple domain entity implementations.